# How to redirect to an existing record in the controller in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, carrierwave

I am building a feature in an app where a user can upload a resume as "pdf" with carrierwave. It should only be possible to upload one file but I can not make the record unique on the database level nor I can use unique as a validation on the model file  because carrierwave does not allow it.

To solve this issue I have decided that I want to at least redirect from the new action to the  show action(existing "download_file") if any record exists so the user will be not able to upload a second file into the database.

I guess my issue is that the new action finds a destroyed resume record with the id: 1 and thats why the form will not be rendered and I would not get redirected to the existing record.

**How can I accomplish this? What am I missing?**

**resumes_contrller.rb**

```
class ResumesController < ApplicationController
  around_filter :catch_not_found
  before_action :find_resume, only: [ :show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def show
  end

  def new
    if Resume.exists?
      redirect_to Resume.find(params[:id])
    else
      @resume = Resume.new
    end
  end

  def create
    @resume = Resume.new resume_params
    if @resume.save
      redirect_to @resume
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @resume.update resume_params
      redirect_to @resume, notice: "Your resume was successfully saved!"
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @resume.destroy
    redirect_to new_resume_path, notice: "Your resume was successfully deleted!"
  end

  private

  def resume_params
    params.require(:resume).permit( :download_file, :remove_download_file)
  end

  def find_resume
    @resume = Resume.find(params[:id])
  end

  def catch_not_found
    yield
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    redirect_to(root_url, :notice => 'Record not found')
  end

end
```

**schema.rb**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170821213418) do

  create_table "resumes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "download_file"
    t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

end
```

**development.log**

```
Started GET "/resumes/new" for 77.8.47.62 at 2017-08-22 19:58:07 +0000
Cannot render console from 77.8.47.62! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by ResumesController#new as HTML
  [1m[36mResume Exists (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  1 AS one FROM "resumes" LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mResume Load (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT  "resumes".* FROM "resumes" WHERE "resumes"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", nil]]
Redirected to https://rails-tutorial-martinbortowski.c9.io/
Completed 302 Found in 10ms (ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)


Started GET "/" for 77.8.47.62 at 2017-08-22 19:58:08 +0000
Cannot render console from 77.8.47.62! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by WelcomesController#index as HTML
  Rendered welcomes/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 59ms (Views: 58.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: Can you just use has_one association between Resumes and User models? That way each user could have only one resume model associated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `Resume.exists?` is akin to asking the question, "Is there at least one resume record in my database?"

If you examine the query it produces, you'll see something like

`` SELECT 1 AS one FROM `resumes` LIMIT 1 ``

I believe what you really want to do is associate the resume to a user. As [Pedro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5666052/pedro-gabriel-lima) said, you'll want to set up a relation between `User` and `Resume` to keep track of the association.

Then you'll want something like

```
class ResumesController < ApplicationController
  # ...

  def new
    if resume = current_user.resume
      redirect_to resume
    else
      @resume = Resume.new
    end
  end

  # ...
end
```

Comment: Well done @metahamza! That is what I meant! For more information http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! I will try to implement it when I solve a new issue... related to associating the user model with resume. I'm getting a no method error on the create action.